# Character rigging: Blender keep offset is not working

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I am new to Blender. I have done rigging for the body part of my character and now I am trying to do facial rigging. When I try to keep offset the facial bone to head and I have click on it, it does not work. The child bone does not follow the parent. I do this in edit mode.
[image]

[image]

I still cant figure out what's going on.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hi, here is my file. Please advice. Thanks [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5414" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5414/)

Comment: someone has already answered you, was it a good answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have several armatures, and they don't even seem to be parented to each other, why don't you put all your bones in one and unique armature with a <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd>, then parent the bones correctly to each other?

Comment: Alright, I'll try to redo. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things you may have done wrong:

1- try selecting the bone that you want to be the child FIRST.

[image: select child first]

2- ofset effect will ONLY work in POSE mode

3- make sure ALL the bones are in the SAME metarig otherwise it won't work as you are trying to do

Wrong way: [image: wrong]
If they are like the ones above, try joining them and repeat the process of parenting

Right way:[image: right]

I Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to keep offset between two bones that aren't from the same armature. I had the same problem, I had my armature and created one more bone by <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> *> Armature > Single Bone*.

The solution is to select your armature then create one bone at the cursor just by pressing <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>. The bone should appear instantly, if not try again, I created the bone right after selecting my armature. Hope this helps.